# Sub navigation with Flow Router in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, flow-router

I have a layout

```
<template name="default">
  {{> header}}
  <aside class="container">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=yield}}
  </aside>
</template>
```

I use Flow Router to navigate to settings:

```
FlowRouter.route( '/settings', {
  name: 'settings',
  action: function ( params, queryParams ) {
    BlazeLayout.render( 'default', { yield: 'settings' } );
  },
} );
```

but my settings page consists of multiple settings pages, so I need a menu at the settings page, so users can navigate to other settings pages (i.e. change password, change name, etc.).

I will have to setup routes for every settings page, but how can I keep a sidebar for navigation between the settings pages?

The routes are

- /settings
- /settings/change-password
- /settings/delete-user

etc.

I think the user should be able to change his/her name at the "main/basic settings page" at route `/settings`.

I guess I could make another layout page which has a sidebar, so I can set the routes with

```
FlowRouter.route( '/settings', {
  name: 'settings',
  action: function ( params, queryParams ) {
    BlazeLayout.render( 'twoSidedLayout', { left: 'settingsMenu', right: 'settings' } );
  },
} );
```

but I'm not quite sure if this is the best way to do it.